# Как выбирать из текста пустую группу, если нет соответствия для re.match?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Допустим есть две строки

```
s_1 = "SELECT * FROM t1;"
s_2 = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id == 1;"
```

И регулярное выражение:

```
regex = re.compile("?:SELECT (?P<columns>.*))(?:FROM (?P<source>))(?:WHERE (?P<where_clause>.*))")
```

Как его поправить чтобы при вызове "regex.match(s_1)" получить группы "columns", "source" и "where_clause" (c "None")?

Comment: Распихать везде `|$`?

Comment: Тогда появиться необходимость в выражении для s_3 = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id == 1 ORDER BY id;"

Comment: может поставить вопрос `(?:WHERE (?P<where_clause>.*))?` тогда этой группы просто не будет если не было where

Comment: [Не вышло.](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E.*(%3F%3Aselect%20(%3FP%3Cselect%3E.%2B))%3F(%3F%3Afrom(%3FP%3Cfrom%3E.%2B))%3F(%3F%3Awhere(%3FP%3Cwhere%3E.%2B))%3F.*%5C%3B%24&test_string=select%20*%20from%20t1%3B%0Aselect%20*%20from%20t1%20where%20c1%20%3D%3D%200%3B&ignorecase=1&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0") Группа - тогда не отображается вообще.

Comment: вы не пробовали существующие инструменты для распознавания SQL типа [sqlparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse)? или на основе одной [из многочисленных библиотек, которые парсеры создают типа: pyparsing, grako, PLY](https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing)?

Comment: @jfs, ещё - нет. На текущий момент задача немного отошла на второй план. Чуть попозже обязательно попробую, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Как я понимаю, первые две части обязательны. Используйте ленивый квантивикатор во второй группе, а третью сделайте опциональной:

```
import re
p = '(?i)SELECT (?P<columns>.*) FROM (?P<source>.*?)(?: WHERE (?P<where_clause>.*))?;$'
strs = ['select * from t1;', 'select * from t1 where c1 == 0;']
for s in strs:
    m = re.match(p, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group("columns"))
        print(m.group("source"))
        print(m.group("where_clause"))
```

См. [демо на Python](http://ideone.com/7PzQeN), выводит

```
*
t1
None
*
t1
c1 == 0
```

Я такжу исхожу из того, что точка с запятой обязательны в конце строки.

- `(?i)` - включает регистронезависимый поиск по шаблону
- `SELECT (?P<columns>.*)` - `SELECT`, пробел,  0+ люых символов
- `FROM (?P<source>.*?)` - пробел, `FROM`, пробел, 0+ люых символов
- `(?: WHERE (?P<where_clause>.*))?` - необязательная незахватывающая группа, находит пробел, `WHERE`, пробел, 0+ любых символов
- `;`  - `;`
- `$` - конец строки (`re.match` привязывает совпадение только к началу строки, но не концу, в `re.fullmatch` не нужен).